# Get the value of the clicked element data in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

How to get html5 `data-attr` value in Angularjs, and click of same function at the same class click.

Like in jquery we click at some class elements and get the current element            `data-num`.

I have to achieve this in angular way.

How can I get the multiple class element click and get current data value ($this)?

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head></head>
    <body ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-click="clicked()" data-num="1" class="same white">White</div>
        <div ng-click="clicked()" data-num="2" class="same green">Green</div>
        <div ng-click="clicked()" data-num="3" class="same red">Red</div>
        <div ng-click="clicked()" data-num="4" class="same white">White</div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        myApp.controller('mainController',function($scope){
        $scope.clicked = function(){
        var id = angular.element('.same').scope();
        console.log(id);
        };
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Two questions for you, is jquery included in angular reference? Also can you put javascript outside of html?

Comment: no i am just giving the demo that we can do this in this way in jquery and my question is how can we achive this in angular way.

Comment: jquery is just for demo purpose

Answer (score 5):

Its **necessary** pass the event in the function

```
<div ng-click="clicked($event)" data-num="2" class="same green">Green</div>
```

Get $event.target in the function, get the JQUery of the DOM and catch the data attr

```
$scope.clicked = function($event){
     var id = $($event.target).data('num');
     console.log(id);
};
```

Solution: [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriobarreto/8tuc90zp/2/)

Anyways, I suggest u not store data in HTML, instead, use your $scope for that:

Consider the following:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myController', function($scope)    {
  $scope.buttons = [
                    { num: 1, className: "class1", description: "desc 1" },
                    { num: 2, className: "class2", description: "desc 2" },
                    { num: 3, className: "class3", description: "desc 3" }
                   ];

  $scope.clicked = function(buttonNumber)
  {
    console.log(buttonNumber);
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-click="clicked(button.num)" class="{{button.className}}">
    {{button.description}}
</div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriobarreto/8tuc90zp/1/)

Comment: Updated the Angular.Element to properly use the JQuery... 

If u dont want to use JQuery u can try: `target.attributes.data.num`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need data attributes.

```
<div ng-click="clicked(1)" class="same white">White</div>
<div ng-click="clicked(2)" class="same green">Green</div>
<div ng-click="clicked(3)" class="same red">Red</div>
<div ng-click="clicked(4)" class="same white">White</div>


$scope.clicked = function(id){
    console.log(id);
};
```

Comment: I also see that, but I guess he want to have access to the DOM to do anything from within the controller

Comment: That is not the proper Angular way. You don't touch the dom to take the data.

Comment: Yeah, in angular way you only "touch DOM" through own directives